# Add array object into another array matching on ids

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using Mongo 4.2. I have a collection with documents in which I have two arrays: studentMcqs and mcq:

studentMcqs:[ 0:{

```
    "id": 2024,
    "answer": "C",
    "bookMarked": false,
    "mcqId": 408041
```

},
1:{....}]

mcq : [ 0:{

```
    "id": 408041,
    "answer": "C",
    "mcqSubject": {
        "id": 289,
        "name": "Mathematics",
        "description": "Mathematics"}
```

}, 1:{....}]

I would like to compare all mcq.id with studentMcqs.mcqId and if they match add mcqSubject object into studentMcqs array.
Would like to do this with aggregation pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
  db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$studentMcqs"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$mcqs"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      mcqs: 1,
      studentMcqs: 1,
      comp_value: {
        $cmp: [
          "$mcqs.id",
          "$studentMcqs.mcqId"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      comp_value: {
        $eq: 0
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      studentMcqs: {
        answer: 1,
        bookMarked: 1,
        id: 1,
        mcqId: 1,
        mcqSubject: "$mcqs.mcqSubject"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      studentMcqs: {
        $push: "$studentMcqs"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can check the working example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/C8oiwBIhB8a)

Comment: Both arrays mentioned above - studentMcq and mcq  are in the same document. $lookup isn't working

Comment: I have updated my answer, and the working example, hope now it helps.